# Umbraco Dashboard Module - How to Make Tab Viewable in Content Nodes?

Tags: umbraco

I created a new module for my user dashboard in the content area.  It works exactly as expected.  However, I have some users who are locked into content nodes further down the tree and therefore can't see the main content root.  When they first login, the new dashboard loads fine, but once they dig into the nodes, it disappears with no way to get back.

What options do I have for making this appear as a tab in the root node of the content they have visible?  I tried the user control wrapper but was getting a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only way I have found to accomplish this is to use the 'umbraco usercontrol wrapper'.  I was able to get my code working out of the box with it by inherting from:

```
System.Web.UI.UserControl, umbraco.editorControls.userControlGrapper.IUsercontrolDataEditor
```

I also added the following to my main class based on an example I found:

```
public string umbracoValue;

public object value
{
    get
    {    
        return umbracoValue;
    }
    set
    {
        umbracoValue = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Those were the only modifications I had to make and it started to function as expected.